# How can I upload to wp media library by foundation zurb ajax

Tags: uploads

I am using zurb ajax image uploader. it works fine to upload to specific folder in FTP.

but I can't really find how to add on wordpress media library. I have to get the thumbnail ids.

Where I can find how to upload wp upload folder and add in database(wp-post, wp-post-meta) as attachment post.

Basically, this is for users photos such as "my more pictures". I believe it should be in wp-user-meta table. any tips, tutorial?

Thanks,